# How to convert SQL Query to JSON format

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am trying to convert my SQL result into JSON format it's showing an error.

SQL Query:

```
 SELECT 
    User.name, 
    Course.title, 
    Member.role 
FROM User 
JOIN Member JOIN Course 
    ON User.user_id = Member.user_id 
    AND Member.course_id = Course.course_id 
ORDER BY 
    Course.title, 
    Member.role DESC, 
    User.name;
```

I have also tried FOR JSON PATH and FOR JSON AUTO but the following error is coming:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'for JSON AUTO' at line 1

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect.

Comment: I thought FOR JSON PATH/AUTO is Microsoft sql server, not MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_OBJECT()` to generate valid json in MySQL.

For example, this would generate a json object for each row, with keys `user_name`, `course_title` and `member_role`, in a column called `js`:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
    'user_name', User.name, 
    'course_title', Course.title, 
    'member_role', Member.role 
) as js
FROM User 
JOIN Member JOIN Course 
    ON User.user_id = Member.user_id 
    AND Member.course_id = Course.course_id 
ORDER BY 
    Course.title, 
    Member.role DESC, 
    User.name;
```

If you want a resultset made of a single row and a single column where all objects are aggregated in an array, you can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` on top of `JSON_OBJECT()`:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(js) js_array
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
        'user_name', User.name, 
        'course_title', Course.title, 
        'member_role', Member.role 
    ) as js
    FROM User 
    JOIN Member JOIN Course 
        ON User.user_id = Member.user_id 
        AND Member.course_id = Course.course_id 
    ORDER BY 
        Course.title, 
        Member.role DESC, 
        User.name
);
```